# Correct format for converting french date from string to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert strings to date, but it's not working for some dates in french. Like in the example below :

```
myDate = datetime.strptime(dateInStringFormat, "%A %d %B %Y  %H:%M:%S")
```

Result with the error : time data '"jeudi 8 septembre 2022 13:51:13"' does not match format '%A %d %B %Y  %H:%M:%S'.

I've tried a lot a variations in the format I can't make it work, anyone know how to do this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
import locale
import datetime
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')

dateInStringFormat = "jeudi 8 septembre 2022 13:51:13"
myDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateInStringFormat, "%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")

print(myDate)
# 2022-09-08 13:51:13

myDate
# datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 8, 13, 51, 13)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's already exactly what I'm doing (I'm importing datetime from datetime, so later I only write it once. But that's the same). I've added the line with "locale" as in your example, still the same error.

Comment: I have no idea why, but I did another test, when I do like you import datetime and your line it works. When using from datetime import datetime and datetime.strptime I have the error about the format. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once and found a module called dateparser to do that:

```
import dateparser
d = dateparser.parse("jeudi 8 septembre 2022 13:51:13")
```

d is now

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 8, 13, 51, 13)
```

Comment: tried to install in (pip install dateparser), package is not found

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/

Comment: yeah, it's write "pip install dateparser", I have the error "No matching distribution found for dateparser